# Blank response on cross domain POST Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, integration, httprequest

I'll  Start with a basic introduction of what i am trying to achieve, basically i am integrating my web application with an ERP([Tally ERP 9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tally_Solutions)) they provide an HTTP/XML API Which is listening on port `9002` and my application is on port `8085` so the problem starts here, when I'am trying to make an ajax call for posting some data i'am getting a blank response,even after getting a success, `And the request is performing the task perfectly` but the only issue is that i am `getting a blank response` Following is my js

```
function postTallyData()
{
var XMLData='<ENVELOPE>...</ENVELOPE>';
var Tallyurl = 'http://localhost:9002';

$.ajax({
    url: Tallyurl,
    type: "POST",
    data: XMLData,
    dataType: "text",
    converters:{"* text": window.String, "text html": true, "text json": jQuery.parseJSON, "text xml": jQuery.parseXML},
    crossdomain: true,
    complete:function(responseXML){
        alert(responseXML);
    var xml = responseXML,
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
    $xml = $(xmlDoc),
    $CREATED = $xml.find("CREATED");
    $ALTERED = $xml.find("ALTERED");
    $LASTVCHID = $xml.find("LASTVCHID");
    $LASTMID = $xml.find("LASTMID");
    $COMBINED = $xml.find("COMBINED");
    $IGNORED = $xml.find("IGNORED");
    $ERRORS = $xml.find("ERRORS");

    if(parseInt($ERRORS.text())>0)
    {
            $LINEERROR = $xml.find("LINEERROR");
            jAlert($LINEERROR.text());
    }
    if(parseInt($CREATED.text())>0)
    {
            $LINEERROR = $xml.find("LINEERROR");
            jAlert("Voucher : "+$LASTVCHID.text()+" Created in Tally");
    }
    }
});
}
```

and here is the firebug screenshot

[image: Request and Response Headers]

[image: Blank Response]

Comment: I don't see Access Control headers in the response, are you cure the console isn't displaying a same origin policy error?